# Xamarin Android Binding Here Navigate .AAR

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, aar

I need help.

I'm trying to bind the HERE SDK Navigate .AAR library into my Xamarin.Android project and I'm having trouble.

I created an “Android Bindings Library (Xamarin)” project in which the .AAR library is located, as this guide indicates:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings

Then, once deployed, I have 72 errors that I must manage to correct by the "metadata.xml" file.

```
<metadata>
    

    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi5.RegisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.RegisterEventListener()' -->
    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi5.UnregisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.UnregisterEventListener()'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi5']/method[@name='registerEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi5']/method[@name='unregisterEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>

    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi24.RegisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.RegisterEventListener()' -->
    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi24.UnregisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.UnregisterEventListener()'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi24']/method[@name='registerEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi24']/method[@name='unregisterEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>

    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi29.RegisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.RegisterEventListener()' -->
    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi29.UnregisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.UnregisterEventListener()'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi29']/method[@name='registerEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi29']/method[@name='unregisterEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    
    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi31.RegisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.RegisterEventListener()' -->
    <!--'PlatformCellManagerApi31.UnregisterEventListener()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PlatformCellManager.UnregisterEventListener()'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi31']/method[@name='registerEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.cell']/class[@name='PlatformCellManagerApi31']/method[@name='unregisterEventListener' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    
    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0111: Type 'CompleteEventArgs' already defines a member called 'CompleteEventArgs' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'CompleteEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'CompleteEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0111: Type 'PauseEventArgs' already defines a member called 'PauseEventArgs' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'PauseEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'PauseEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0111: Type 'ProgressEventArgs' already defines a member called 'ProgressEventArgs' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p1'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IMapUpdateProgressListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P1' -->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.maploader']/interface[@name='MapUpdateProgressListener']/method[@name='onComplete']" name="managedName">OnMapUpdateComplete</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.maploader']/interface[@name='MapUpdateProgressListener']/method[@name='onPause']" name="managedName">OnMapUpdatePause</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.maploader']/interface[@name='MapUpdateProgressListener']/method[@name='onProgress']" name="managedName">OnMapUpdateProgress</attr>

    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0111: Type 'PauseEventArgs' already defines a member called 'PauseEventArgs' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'PauseEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'PauseEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0111: Type 'ProgressEventArgs' already defines a member called 'ProgressEventArgs' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p1'
    Com.Here.Sdk.Maploader.IDownloadRegionsStatusListener.cs: error CS0102: The type 'ProgressEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P1'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.maploader']/interface[@name='DownloadRegionsStatusListener']/method[@name='onPause']" name="managedName">OnDownloadRegionsPause</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.sdk.maploader']/interface[@name='DownloadRegionsStatusListener']/method[@name='onProgress']" name="managedName">OnDownloadRegionsProgress</attr>

    <!--Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.IPositioningSession.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'PositioningSession'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.IPositioningSession.cs: error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'PositioningSession' must not specify different base classes
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'ICloseableSession.Close()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'ICloseableSession.Open()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaObject.Handle'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.SetJniIdentityHashCode(int)'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference)'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates)'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.UnregisterFromRuntime()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.DisposeUnlessReferenced()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.Disposed()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.Finalized()'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.JniIdentityHashCode'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.PeerReference'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IJavaPeerable.JniManagedPeerState'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Posclient.Pos.PositioningSession.cs: error CS0535: 'PositioningSession' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.posclient.pos']/class[@name='PositioningSession']" name="name">MyPositioningSession</attr>

    <!--Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Consent.Internal.IConsentClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'ConsentClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Consent.Internal.IConsentClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.positioning.consent.internal']/class[@name='ConsentClient']" name="name">MyConsentClient</attr>

    <!--Com.Here.Services.Test.Internal.ILocationTestClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'LocationTestClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Test.Internal.LocationTestClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.test.internal']/class[@name='LocationTestClient']" name="name">MyLocationTestClient</attr>

    <!--Com.Here.Services.Radiomap.Internal.IRadioMapManager.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'RadioMapManager'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Radiomap.Internal.RadioMapManager.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute
    Com.Here.Services.Radiomap.Internal.IRadioMapManager.cs: error CS0509: 'RadioMapManagerConsts': cannot derive from sealed type 'RadioMapManager'-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.radiomap.internal']/class[@name='RadioMapManager']" name="name">MyRadioMapManager</attr>

    <!--Com.Here.Services.Radiomap.Internal.IRadioMapManagerClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'RadioMapManagerClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Radiomap.Internal.RadioMapManagerClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.radiomap.internal']/class[@name='RadioMapManagerClient']" name="name">MyRadioMapManagerClient</attr>
    
    <!--Com.Here.Time.Duration.cs(20,67,20,96): error CS0535: 'Duration' does not implement interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'-->
    <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.here.time']/class[@name='Duration']">
        <method name="compareTo" return="int" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
            <parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object" />
        </method>
    </add-node>

    
    <!-- Zero warning - Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Upload.Internal.IUploadClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'UploadClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Upload.Internal.UploadClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.positioning.upload.internal']/class[@name='UploadClient']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    
    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Auth.Internal.IAuthClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'AuthClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Auth.Internal.IAuthClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.positioning.auth.internal']/class[@name='AuthClient']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    
    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Analytics.Internal.IUsageTrackingClient.cs(508,24,508,43): error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'UsageTrackingClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Positioning.Analytics.Internal.UsageTrackingClient.cs(19,3,19,35): error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.positioning.analytics.internal']/class[@name='UsageTrackingClient']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    
    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Services.Playback.Internal.IMeasurementPlaybackClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MeasurementPlaybackClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Playback.Internal.MeasurementPlaybackClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.playback.internal']/class[@name='MeasurementPlaybackClient']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
        
    <!--Zero warning - Com.Here.Services.Location.Internal.IPositioningClient.cs: error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'PositioningClient'; another partial declaration of this type exists
    Com.Here.Services.Location.Internal.PositioningClient.cs: error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Register' attribute-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.here.services.location.internal']/class[@name='PositioningClient']" name="visibility">protected</attr>

    <!--33 warnings - Com.Here.Odnp.Util.AssetCopyTask.cs: error CS0534: 'AssetCopyTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[]?)'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Util.OdnpIOUtils.cs: error CS0111: Type 'OdnpIOUtils' already defines a member called 'Close' with the same parameter types-->
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.util']" />
    
    <!--130 warnings Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0102: The type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already contains a definition for 'cb_setInitialMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0111: Type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already defines a member called 'GetSetInitialMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_Handler' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0111: Type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already defines a member called 'n_SetInitialMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0102: The type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already contains a definition for 'cb_updateMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_'
    Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0111: Type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already defines a member called 'GetUpdateMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_Handler' with the same parameter types
    Com.Here.Odnp.Wifi.WifiFilterTimestamp.cs: error CS0111: Type 'WifiFilterTimestamp' already defines a member called 'n_UpdateMeasurements_Ljava_util_List_' with the same parameter types-->
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.here.odnp.wifi']" />
    
</metadata>
```

Here Navigate project compiles, but not the solution. Here the error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error in obj\Debug\120\lp\171\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class:
Type com.here.services.playback.MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\120\lp\171\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class, obj\Debug\120\lp\27\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\120\lp\171\jl\bin\classes.jar
com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:98)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.main(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:4)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\120\lp\171\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.75.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:75)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1133)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:2212)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:85)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Type com.here.services.playback.MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\120\lp\171\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class, obj\Debug\120\lp\27\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/here/services/playback/MeasurementPlaybackApi$Listener$Error.class
    at
```

I think the error is due to my "metadata" file. Not being a "binding library" expert, I'm sure it contains errors. That's why I need your help XD

I try my best with these guides :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings

Comment: Hello by the way :)